# Change users wallpaper without logging in as the user in XP

Tags: windows-xp, user-profile

I have admin access to the computer.

What I want to do is change a users wallpaper to something else but without logging in as the user.
There must be a config file or something where these settings are kept for the user.

I'm assuming it's in /Documents and Settings/UserName but I haven't found the file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The per-user wallpaper setting is stored, in the registry, as a `REG_SZ` value named `Wallpaper`, under the key `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop`.

If the user is logged in, or their hive is otherwise mounted, you would find the key under `HKEY_USERS\User's SID`.  If the user is not logged in, you would need to mount their hive under `HKEY_USERS` first.  User hives are found in the user's profile, `%USERPROFILE%`, typically under "C:\Documents and Settings\username\" (Windows XP) or C:\Users\username\ (Windows 7) and are named "NTUSER.DAT".

Alternatively, you could use Group Policy to enforce a specific wallpaper.